# How to add marker/symbol to colorbar

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, symbols, colorbar

I want to add a marker/special tick mark  in my MATLAB `colorbar`. For example, lets say I have a colorbar scale from `-2` to `3` and my critical value is `-1.8`, how can I add a marker of the value by symbol/marker?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to fetch the [colorbar](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html) position, compute the location where you want your marker, and place an [annotation object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) (like an arrow) there:

```
% Plot sample data, displaying color bar and getting its limits:

data = peaks();
imagesc(data);
hBar = colorbar();
cLimits = caxis();
hold on;

% Select and plot a point of interest:

point = [31 15];
value = data(point(1), point(2));
plot(point(2), point(1), 'r+');

% Compute location of color bar pointer and make annotation:

barPos = get(hBar, 'Position');
xArrow = barPos(1)+barPos(3)/2+[0.05 0];
yArrow = barPos(2)+barPos(4)*(value-cLimits(1))/diff(cLimits)+[0 0];
hArrow = annotation('textarrow', xArrow, yArrow, ...
                    'String', num2str(value, '%.2f'), 'Color', 'r');
```

[image]

If the figure is resized, the position of the annotation object may shift with respect to the color bar. One way to avoid this is to tweak the axes and color bar resize behavior with the following code:

```
axesPos = get(gca, 'Position');
set(hBar, 'Location', 'manual');
set(gca, 'Position', axesPos);
```

This should allow the annotation object to stay fixed to the proper spot over the color bar.

Answer (score 4):

Here is yet another option - just add/change the tick label at the specific value:

```
MarkTxt = '<-Mark';
imagesc(rand(10)-2) % something to plot
colormap('jet')
CB = colorbar;

% in case you DON'T want the value to appear:
value = -1.8;
t = find(CB.Ticks==value);
if ~isempty(t)
    CB.TickLabels{t} = MarkTxt;
else
    [CB.Ticks,ord] = sort([CB.Ticks value],'ascend');
    t = CB.Ticks==value;
    CB.TickLabels{t} = MarkTxt;
end

%% OR - in case you want the value to appear:
value = -1.24;
t = find(CB.Ticks==value);
if ~isempty(t)
    CB.TickLabels{t} = [CB.TickLabels{t} MarkTxt];
else
    [CB.Ticks,ord] = sort([CB.Ticks value],'ascend');
    t = CB.Ticks==value;
    CB.TickLabels{t} = [CB.TickLabels{t} MarkTxt];
end
```

Without the value:
[image: CB mark]

With the value:
[image: CB mark value]

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add [`text`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) outside the plotting area and use that for your marker:

```
A = rand(15);
f=figure;
imagesc(A);
text(7,7,'X','Color','red') % Put a red X in the middle
text(17.5,size(A,1)*(1-A(7,7)),'<marker'); % Set a marker on the colour bar for the middle point
colorbar
```

Which results in:

[image]

*I haven't found a way yet to plot a marker* over *the colour bar, as the colour bar is not one of the plot children which I can use in `uistack` for some reason.*